# What's the relation between $\mathbf E(X)$ and $\mathbf E(e^X)$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, expected-value

> Given $\mathbf E(X)=0$ and $-1\le X\le 1$, show that $\mathbf E(\text{exp}(\sqrt{2}X))\le e^{\sqrt{2}}-\sqrt{2}$.

It seems that Jensen's inequality will help, but I have no idea.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Since $-1 \le X \le 1$, we have $X^k \le 1$, and thus, $E[X^k] \le 1$ for all integers $k \ge 2$. Also, you are given $E[X] = 0$.

Now, use $e^{X\sqrt{2}} = \displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(\sqrt{2})^k}{k!}X^k$ along with linearity of expectation and see what you get.

Comment: One needs something stronger than linearity of expectation since the series is infinite.

Comment: @StubbornAtom: Can I use the condition $X \leq 1$ directly, $E[e^{\sqrt{2}X}] \leq e^{\sqrt{2}}$?

Comment: @Alex Lol you are asking me? I think so.

Comment: You can. However the original question asked to show that $E[e^{X\sqrt{2}}] \le 3$. So proving that $E[e^{X\sqrt{2}}] \le e^{\sqrt{2}} \approx 4.11$ would not be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

The following is well-known:-

**If $X$ is a random variable(real valued and to speak very formally $X$ is an integrable/measurable real valued random variable) and $\varphi$ is a convex function then $\varphi(E(X))\leq E(\varphi(X))$**

Now the exponential function is convex. This answer the question you asked in the title of your question. But it'll not help you prove $E(e^{\sqrt{2}X})<3$.